# UITable first section built

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

sorry for silly question, I am a beginner in obj-c.

I wanted to add a "load more" feature in my table, I performed that by creating 2 section. The problem now is that the first section to be built from the app is the second, not the first.

Attached the log of the first call of cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
2012-10-02 00:07:50.626 ----[6321:c07] item :0
2012-10-02 00:07:50.626 ----[6321:c07] section :1
```

Isn't supposed to be something like this:

```
2012-10-02 00:07:50.626 ----[6321:c07] item :0
2012-10-02 00:07:50.626 ----[6321:c07] section :0
```

So my app, at first launch, show only the "load more" cell, instead of the first rows of the first section. After the first "press" of the "load more" button, everything works properly.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` make sure you are checking the `indexPath` variable for its `section` before initializing and return the `UITableViewCell`. If it's the "load more" cell, `indexPath.section == 1` will be true. If `indexPath.section == 0`, it is your first section table cells.

Also make sure `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` and `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` are returning the correct numbers.

Upon rereading your question, it sounds like you need to initialize your table with cell data before "load more" is pressed. What exactly does "load more" do to your table view's backing data?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You led me in the right way! The problem was that at the first call of numberOfRowsInSection method i returned 0 for section 0, and 1 for section 1, so i suppose that the app will build only the section with a positive number of rows. Fixing the returning value all works fine. You save my day! :)